# Вызов вложенных async методов

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

```
internal async Task<Something> InitSomethingAsync()
{
    return await _some.SetSomethingFlags(SomethingtFlagsAsync(_sportDataDays));
}
```

---

```
public async Task<EventPropertiesFilter> SetSomethingFlags(Task<HashSet<ValueTuple<long, int>>> paramTask)
{
    _fieldValue = _fieldValue ?? await paramTask;
    return this;
}
```

---

```
public async Task<HashSet<ValueTuple<long, int>>> SomethingtFlagsAsync()
{
    return await _cache.GetCacheItemAsync<HashSet<ValueTuple<long, int>>>(async () => await GetSomething());
}
```

Внутри `GetCacheItemAsync` используется 'copy-past' реализация [SemaphorSlim](http://www.tomdupont.net/2015/11/net-semaphore-slim-that-supports-keys.html), `_useCount` которого будет равен 1 если метод `SetSomething` вызывать два раза, ибо `_fieldValue` уже проинициализировано. Т.е занятый семафор будет в таком состоянии до завершения запроса. Не очень понятна причина.

Семафор используется в рамках `using` блока и если я правильно понимаю реализацию, то по окончанию этого блока, семафор должен быть удален из общего словаря:

```
private void Release(SemaphoreWrapper wrapper)    
{   
    lock (_lock)  
    {
        var isEmpty = wrapper.Release();

        if (!isEmpty) 

            return; 

        _wrapperMap.Remove(wrapper.Key);
    }
}
```

---

**UPD**. Сомнительное условие и прочий код был переписан, но тем не менее хотелось бы иметь больше понимания о возникшей проблеме.